# JavaScript setInterval new Image (Online User Counter)

Tags: javascript, counter, setinterval, onmousemove

Okay,

So I've built a JS that communicates to the server (php).

a User enters the website, it adds a 24 hour cookie and a session cookie (both of which have a random number generated "key". If they have already been on the site, such as a session cookie or the 24 hour, the same key will be used.

Every 15 seconds they are on the page, it Pings a "new Image()" url, that sends the "key" to the server. the server then logs that key with their IP address, that way the combos could be endless and multiple users on the same IP can be entered.

I monitor their mouse movements. (and if they do not move the mouse on the page for more than 60 seconds, they are now idle and I no longer send the Ping), the database removes users that have been idle/inactive for 3 minutes or have not sent a ping. (gives some buffer and forgiveness time). anyways all that seems to work great.

But I started logging the Time they entered and the last time they sent a ping to the server. The numbers are outstanding. There is a HUGE amount of users on the site too long to be real. If they dont move the mouse, they are idle, however, 2,000+ users online, 150 of them have been on the site longer than 20 minutes and moving the mouse (or atleast fouling javascript that they are moving the mouse), and its messing up the avg duration time.

I am lost for words. I'm trying to build a very accurate online counter with avg duration, but how could someone be on the site that long, what's causing them to continue to send a ping to the server. Makes no sense. Ive looked at user agents, its all different browsers, and they dont seem to be Bots that are known, such as googlebot. They are rogue.

These users will remain actively sending a ping to the server every 15 seconds for days, I have limited to 120 ping max if they do not click a page (thats 30 minutes), but the pings continue, its crazy.

```
var onses = decodeURIComponent(_srread('__SE3'));
var oncook = decodeURIComponent(_srread('__ON3'));
if (onses == '') {
    var key = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999) + 1).toString();
    var bk = key;
}
else {
    var bk = onses;
}
sr_pinge(1);
var idleTime = 0;
var pingcap = 0;
var idleInterval = setInterval(sr_idletime, 1000);
function addEvent (evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(evnt, func, false);
    }
    else if (elem.attachEvent) {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + evnt, func);
    }
    else {
        elem[evnt] = func;
    }
}
addEvent('mousemove', document, sr_movements);
function sr_movements () {
    idleTime = 0;
}
function sr_idletime () {
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 60) {
        if (this.ping) {
            clearInterval(this.ping);
            this.ping = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (this.ping) {} else {
            sr_ping();
        }
    }
}
function sr_ping () {
    this.ping = setInterval(function () {
        sr_pinge(0);
    }, 15000);
}
function sr_pinge (pv) {
    pingcap = pingcap + 1;
    if (pingcap > 120) return false;
    returned = 0;
    if (pv == 1) {
        if (oncook == '') {
            var ontime = new Date(), onexpire = ontime.setTime(ontime.getTime() + 86400000);
            _srset('__ON3', encodeURIComponent(bk), ontime);
            _srset('__SE3', encodeURIComponent(bk));
        }
        else {
            if (onses == '') {
                returned = 1;
                _srset('__SE3', encodeURIComponent(bk));
            }
        }
    }
    var im = new Image();
    var img = 'http://'+Domain+'/o/?type=on&v='+Version+'&pv='+pv+'&r='+returned+'&k='+encodeURIComponent(bk);        img += ' & a = '+account_id+' & dn = '+en(docdomain)+' & dt = ' + new Date().getTime();
    im.src = img;
}
```

I'm not sure where to post this, but I want to be sure the code I've built would work well within many browsers, my guess could be something isnt functioning somewhere, and people are active when they shouldnt be. But that would mean they left the website on and forgot about it or something. But its like 20% of the traffic. and usually there is about 1-2 thousand users online at a given time.